# CSV download is unavailabe in the AWS Billing Dashboard / Bills page

Tags: amazon-web-services

When I visit AWS management console => AWS Billing Dashboard => Bills page, select the preferable date (e.g. May 2022) and Download CSV, I cannot download CSV but following error appears:

> (!) The Monthly Usage Report CSV is only available for the months
> after opting in via the Preferences page

So I tried to find the Preferences page to opt in but I could not find it.
Where can I find it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can reference the links as below.

> 6. If you get the following error, please pick the most recent month and try again. If you continue to receive this error please reference
>    the Configure Monthly Reports Lab Guide for steps to enable your
>    Monthly Report.

https://www.wellarchitectedlabs.com/cost/100_labs/100_4_cost_and_usage_analysis/3_cost_usage_download/
https://wellarchitectedlabs.com/cost/100_labs/100_1_aws_account_setup/9_monthly_report/

Answer (score 0):

`Its in` AWS Cost and Usage Reports`:

[image]